# how to store link graph information in matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, graph, cell-array

I'd like to store information of this matrix for link clustering purpose. For example

```
   a =
     1     3   
     8     0
```

I'd like to store row and column information as the key of my dictionary and other information related as values; i.e.store (row,col)=val (1,1)=1; (1,2)=3;  something like this

```
 Structure A:
 key:         (1,1) (1,2)
 attribute1:    1      3    
 attribute2: ..
```

information regarding row 2:

```
 Structure B:
 key:         (2,1) (2,2)
 attribute1:    8      0    
 attribute2: ..
```

Then, do some calculation, for example to find intersection of two structure in key values that would be (1,2) (not sensitive to order).

Previously,I used cell array for storing such structure when the key value was node ids not links (pair). But now if i want to store link information What is the best structure to use for this purpose? Struct, Map? cell of cell array? if I use struct should I use key vale as a cell array? how should I proceed?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

What information do you need to store? (row,col) that you named as examples are easily, why do you want to store them!

Comment: I'd like row,col information be the key for my structure and other information as the attribute and value for this key. Then, I'd like to be able to compare keys with each other. For example search for (1,2) entry in key attribute of structure 1 and 2 as mentioned. If I cant store pair of values as key in the map structure, maybe I should change them to character and then compare them..